# get_identity() of Django REST Framework 2 substitute in version 3?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In DRF2 there was [get_identity()](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/serializers#how-identity-is-determined-when-performing-bulk-updates) method, that can be overridden to customize matching serialized data with database objects.

In the new version it's gone, but is there a way to do the same thing?

Comment: Are you looking to do bulk updates?

Comment: @chucksmash Not only